# How to save all keys value into an array variable

Tags: python, json, bash, shell, curl

I have a cURL command which return some json results.

I have :

```
{  
    "all":[  
        {
            "id":"1"
        },
        {
            "id":"2"
        },
        {
            "id":"3"
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal is to retreive all IDs values into an array in Bash. I know how to retreive a particular ID knowing the position.
Here is what I tried :

```
#!/bin/bash
CURL_COMM=$(curl https://DOMAIN/API -H "X-Auth-Token: TOKEN" | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['all'][0]['id']")
echo "$CURL_COMM"
```

This will output `1` as expected, but I need to retreive the other IDs without knowing the number of element. Is that possible ?

And is it possible to retreive values contained in array, like :

```
{  
    "all":[  
        {
            "id":"1",
            "actions":[  
                "power",
                "reboot"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"2"
        },
        {
            "id":"3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to retreive the actions list ?

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: It's on the command line, did you read the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
python -c "import sys, json; print [i['id'] for i in json.load(sys.stdin)['all']]"
```

Answer (score 2):

As always, [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) makes working with JSON from a command line easy.

First one as a string holding a JSON array:

```
$ CURL_COMM=$(curl blah | jq -c '[ .all[].id | tonumber ]')
$ echo $CURL_COMM
[1,2,3]
```

First one as a bash array:

```
$ CURL_COMM=($(curl blah | jq '.all[].id | tonumber'))
$ echo ${CURL_COMM[1]}
2
```

Second one:

```
$ jq -c '.all[0].actions' example.json
["power","reboot"]
```